# AspectJ Expression for an existing annotation, pointcut after annotation but before method execution

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, spring-annotations

Here's the existing code:

```
@Transactional
//  <-- Want to Pointcut to here, after Transactional is done, before method execution
public String getUsername(int userId) {
     ...
}
```

Trying to pointcut to the commented line, here's what I tried so far:

```
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional) " +
        " && !target(org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport)")
public Object runQueryWithinTransaction(ProceedingJoinPointjp) throws Throwable {
     ...
}
```

Also tried setting the order of my aspect to LowestPrecedence. Despite all of this, I still see my Aspect being called before Transactional's "invokeWithinTransaction" method. Tried "@After" but that was executed after my "getUsername" method. Tried "@Before", for no reason, but that obviously didn't help.

What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by setting precedence in my aspect like so:

```
@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect, *")
public class MyAspect {
    ....
}
```

Thanks to @kriegaex, in case you aren't using AspectJ and regular Spring AOP, you should be trying to use `@Ordered` and `@Order` annotations. @Order on Spring Transactional annotation can be set in `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation, and set a lower precedence (or none at all, since lowest precedence is default) for your own Aspect.

Comment: If this works it means you are using AspectJ (probably via load-time weaving agent) and not Spring AOP. Is this correct? In the context of AOP-related questions for Spring projects, you should always explicitly mention that because the default use case for most Spring users is to use the built-in Spring AOP as an "AOP lite" solution unless they need advanced AspectJ features. For Spring AOP aspects execution order can be changed via `@Ordered` and `@Order` annotations, for AspectJ you use `@DeclarePrecedence`. Thus, the correct answer to your question depends on the AOP framework used.